# Incorrect String Value in MySQL db

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, encoding, sqlalchemy

I am running a webapp on Ubuntu 16.04.4.
The stack is as follows

Python 3.5.2
MySQL 5.7.22
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy

The webapp has a feature for admins to upload some text using a xlsx. file which is read with openpyxl inside the webapp. However while saving I am getting errors like:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC4\\x9B nep...'
```

In the beginning I was able to delete the characters which were making troubles (e.g. zero width whitespace). But now I am not able to do it anymore like this.

Reading a bit on the internet I think it could be that my db is not using utf8mb4. Could someone lead me to update my db and all its tables? Because I do not know anything about SQL and stuff. 
As the webapp is used in production I do not like to try tutorials which are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work now. I did following steps:

1. Started the mysql cli with:
   `mysql -u root -p`
2. Logged in using the root pw.
3. Checked the default parameters using
   `show variables like "%character%";`
   which gave me:

   ```
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | Variable_name            | Value                      |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
   | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
   | character_set_database   | latin1                     |
   | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
   | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
   | character_set_server     | latin1                     |
   | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
   | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   ```

   and 
   `show variables like "%collation%";`
   which gave me

   ```
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | Variable_name        | Value             |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
   | collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
   | collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   ```
4. So I edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
   I added:

   ```
   [client]
   default-character-set = utf8mb4

   [mysql]
   default-character-set = utf8mb4

   [mysqld]
   character-set-server = utf8mb4
   collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   ```
5. Restarting mysql (`sudo service mysql restart`) and running the same commands as above now gave me

   ```
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | Variable_name            | Value                      |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
   | character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
   | character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
   | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
   | character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
   | character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
   | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
   | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   ```

   and

   ```
   +----------------------+--------------------+
   | Variable_name        | Value              |
   +----------------------+--------------------+
   | collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
   | collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
   | collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
   +----------------------+--------------------+
   ```
6. So I looked up the table settings using 
   `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM databasename;`
   They still used stuff like `latin1_swedish_ci`
7. I used following to change the database setting:
   `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
   and following for each table:

   ```
   use databasename;
   ALTER TABLE assessments CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```

   8. Looking up again the table settings showed that `latin1_swedish_ci` was now changed to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
   9. Then I changed the sqlalchemy connection url to use `?encoding=utf8mb4` at the end.
   10. Restarted mysql again and the webapp. Since then it's working properly.